# How to assess AIC of a training model on a testing dataset using the coefficients of the training model?

Tags: r, regression, glm, training-data

Let's say I have a lognormal model like this (an example) where I have already split my training and testing datasets:

glm(log(Death)~Age+Medication+IQ,data=death.rate.train,link=gaussian(link="identity"))

How would I create another GLM model with the beta coefficients from the training dataset in order to see the overall goodness of fit using AIC or BIC, etc.? Could I possibly do something like this, where the variable.train would be the coefficients from the training model?

AIC(glm(log(Death)~offset(Age.train+Medication.train+IQ.train),data=death.rate.test,link=gaussian(link="identity")))?

Is there an easier way? (Please tell me there is!! I have a lot more variables with multiple factor levels.)

Comment: Maybe you could use the predict function from stats package to test your model and coefficients from training dataset on testing dataset ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that? If I do predict(train.model,newdata=testdata,type="response"), I will just get the predicted death values. How can I form a model with the coefficients from the training dataset?